# Deserialize simple-plain XML to compose object

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I need deserialize this XML structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?> 
<vspaccess>
  <vpstxid>A99C4831-D037-6A95-9DCF-E1CEC537875D</vpstxid> 
  <txstateid>0</txstateid> 
  <amount>0</amount> 
  <started /> 
  <completed /> 
  <vpsauthcode>0</vpsauthcode> 
  <batchid>0</batchid> 
  <aborted /> 
  <released /> 
  <applyavscv2>0</applyavscv2> 
  <apply3dsecure>0</apply3dsecure> 
  <authattempt>0</authattempt> 
  <threedattempt>0</threedattempt> 
  <eci>0</eci> 
  <t3mscore>0</t3mscore> 
  <surcharge>0</surcharge> 
 </vspaccess>
```

To a class with this structure :

```
[XmlRoot("vspaccess")]
public class GetTransactionDetailResponse 
{
  [XmlElement(Type=typeof(TransactionDetail), Order = 1)]
  public TransactionDetail Detail { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionDetail
{
  [XmlElement("vpstxid", Order = 1)]
  public string VpsTxId { get; set; }

  // Rest of properties
}
```

However, when I try it, the `"Detail"` property of the class `GetTransactionDetailResponse` 
always is `null`.

I've tried combining a lot of overloads of the `XmlElement` attribute but the result
is always null.

I can't modify the xml structure because is returned from a web service and the structure
of the class `GetTransactionDetailResponse` is fixed because is used in a lot of places in the code (is legacy code).

There are a lot of samples in stackoverflow in relation to serializing/deserializing XML from/to objects, but i haven't found any that is similar to my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the TransactionDetail class to be like this:

```
[XmlRoot("vspaccess")]
public class TransactionDetail
{
    public string vpstxid;
    public byte txstateid;
    public byte amount;
    public object started;
    public object completed;
    public byte vpsauthcode;
    public byte batchid;
    public object aborted;
    public object released;
    public byte applyavscv2;
    public byte apply3dsecure;
    public byte authattempt;
    public byte threedattempt;
    public byte eci;
    public byte t3mscore;
    public byte surcharge;
}
```

Then you can write de-serialization code like this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TransactionDetail));
TransactionDetail td = null;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    td = (TransactionDetail)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Finally, you can set Detail property of the `GetTransactionDetailResponse` object with the `TransactionDetail` object that you just deserialized.